# Confusion of using rest api testing

Tags: java, rest-api

I have done my selenium functional automation testing Now my company gave a task to do rest api testing .There were several tools are there like Jmeter, soap ui etc... and also we can add rest-assured jar files to eclipse with java.  Anybody please help me which I will choose.? Which tools are most companys using ?  Anybody please help me how to start learning. What are the important point that i should be learn before starting with rest api ?

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody please help me which I will choose.?

I was at same point a few days back where you are right now.
As it will consume time to build own framework to test rest APIs, so i had dropped this idea.

While choosing tool, I found **Postman** easy to learn and use. So far i am using it in different projects from 3-4 months now and it's good.

> Which tools are most companys using ?

Different companies use different tools according to their team's capabilities. So we cannot say that if x company is using a tool then that tool is best to use.

> Anybody please help me how to start learning

For this you need to check the tutorials of whatever tool you choose.

> What are the important point that i should be learn before starting
>   with rest api ?

Answer of this question is broad and vary person to person. But you should be aware what are rest APIs , how these work, their implementation. behavior of results. Common type of APIs. etc